# my lubuntu gui can not login by my user and guest user

Tags: lubuntu, login, lightdm, login-screen

I can not login in the gui, it flash and back to login gui after I input password, this is in my `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log` file:

```
** (lightdm-gtk-greeter:2893): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: 
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

** (lightdm-gtk-greeter:2893): WARNING **: Failed to load user image: 
Failed to open file '/home/liao/.face': No such file or directory
```

Because it is not only one user can not login, the guest user can not login either. My lubuntu version: Linux ubuntu 3.16.0-31-generic #41-Ubuntu